# Videos stored in jwplayer make them secure

Tags: jwplayer

is there a way to make the videos stored in the http://content.jwplatform.com/ site more secure? like time token based? streaming?

```
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("video").setup({
    file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/xxxxxxxx.mp4?token=1234",
    autostart: true,
    controls: false,
    repeat: true
});
```

This is to minimize direct user access to the source file and that the file is only played in certain domains to avoid abuse of the file.

Comment: From JW Player's support forum: they dont currently support [restricting domains](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16311948-restrict-domain), they suggest using [url signing](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1433647-url-token-signing) instead

Answer (score 0):

Currently hls will by default provide content signed urls in the JW Dashboard. The expiration time is set for 1 hour. Signed urls will be the default very soon for all JW-supported file types.